# How to conditionally use Authorization based on appsettings in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebApi in which I using OAuth based Authentication and Authorization. On the Controllers, I add the Authorize attributes providing the policy name to apply. However, for my local development, I want to skip the authentication/authorization part. Lets say, I add some appsettings to indicate whether to use AA or not. Based on that, in the Configure method in startup class, I can conditionally use below code snippet to activate the required middleware.

```
if(configuration.GetSection("OAuth:Enabled") == true)
{
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
}
```

However, my controller is still decorated with Authorize attribute. Currently, unless I comment it out on each controller, i cannot disable Authorization. Is there any suggestion on how this can be achieved or any alternate option to temporarily bypass Authorization based on single configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: @MajidQafouri the link that you provided is unrelated.

Comment: You don't need to disable the attributes. Those are just markers telling the auth middleware what to do. Without that middleware they're inactive. What's the problem with the current solution? `still decorated with Authorize attribute.` why is that a problem?

Comment: `UseAuthentication` and `UseAuthorization` are used to enable the authentication/authorization middleware no matte what method is used. They aren't specific to OAuth. OAuth is added by ASP.NET Core Identity. Did you disable that as well? What does your `Statup.cs` look like? And what's the *actual problem* ?

Comment: I am looking to disable both Authentication and Authorization in runtime, based on a single configuration change. I need this for 2 purposes. One for simplifying developer testing so they can just focus functional changes. 2) We are in process of moving to OAuth from Siteminder. At the same time, there are ongoing functional changes in these APIs. So if I have to test the API with OAuth and without OAuth, i need to maintain 2 separate branches and keep on merging functional changes in the OAuth branch. So its becoming an overhead and we have around 10 APIs where we have same challenge.

Comment: Also, current version of WebAPI doesn't use Authorization. Its only needed when we move to OAuth.

Comment: That's not what I asked. What's the problem with what you already tried? Why do you want to "disable" the attributes? Why isn't disabling the middleware enough?

Answer (score 1):

You *could* just create a custom configuration and wrap `Authorize` attributes with compiler conditionals e.g.

```
#if !BYPASS_AUTH
[Authorize()]
#endif
public void Blah(...)
```

... but this is a bit messy, and if you're like me and don't like seeing compiler directives littered throughout your code, you'd probably like to hide this away in a custom authorize attribute or something where you can do imperative auth as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-imperative-authorization).

There's probably multiple ways to do this, but here's one way using an `IAsyncActionFilter` & `TypeFilterAttribute` implementations. This approach allows me to dependency inject the `IAuthorizationService` for imperative auth.

Note: following code is untested, so might be typos and might need refinement...

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
   public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(string policyName)
      : base(typeof(CustomAuthorizeAsyncActionFilterAttribute))
   {
      Arguments = new object[] {policyName};
   }
}

public class CustomAuthorizeAsyncActionFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
   private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
   private readonly AuthSettings _authSettings;
   private readonly string _policyName;

   public CustomAuthorizeAsyncActionFilterAttribute(
      IAuthorizationService authorizationService,
      IOptions<AuthSettings> authSettings
      string policyName)
   {
      _authorizationService = authorizationService;
      _authSettings = authSettings.Value;
      _policyName = policyName;
   }

   public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
   {
      if (_authSettings.AuthEnabled)
      {
         var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(context.HttpContext.User, context.ActionArguments, _policyName);
         if (authorizationResult.Succeeded)
         {
            await next.Invoke();
         }
         else
         {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
         }
      }
      else
      {
         await next.Invoke();
      }
   }
}
```

Oh and you'll need to change all your `[Authorize]` attributes to `[CustomAuthorize]`.

Comment: The question is how to disable authentication at runtime through settings, not at build time. It's unclear what the problem with question's code is too. The easiest way to disable authentication is to not enable it in the first place

Comment: imperative auth inside CustomAuthorizeAsyncActionFilterAttribute. Can use config setting instead of compiler directive to turn auth on/off at runtime...

Comment: Again, how are *runtime settings* going to affect build-time compiler directives that were used to disable authentication at build time, perhaps 1 month before the settings changed? What happens if authentication is disabled in production by mistake? This isn't a "be careful". A *lot* of reported breaches are caused by accidentally disabled authentication

Comment: updated answer to make it clearer... note: injected IOptions<AuthSettings>into CustomAuthorizeAsyncActionFilterAttribute instead of using compiler directive (which I did explain in answer, but might not have been clear).
FWIW I think just commenting out the auth middleware is the right answer, but not sure why that wasn't working for question author. The only benefit of my approach is it's no-code change, just config...

Comment: Commenting out Authorize attribute works. But I want to avoid that code change as I will need to do this on every controller and in around 10 APIs. Also, we are in process of moving to OAuth from Siteminder and Authorization is needed, only when we move to OAuth. Current version is not using it. At the same time, there are ongoing functional changes in these APIs. So if I have to test the API with OAuth and wo OAuth, i need to maintain 2 separate branches and keep on merging functional changes in the OAuth branch. So its becoming an overhead to constantly maintain multiple branches on all APIs